# Which database is music app on ios 8.4 querying for artist pictures?

Tags: music, ios, graphics

I wonder, which database apple uses for artist pictures in the music app on iOS 8.4 and how missing pictures for certain artists can be added?

Pretty sure it's something internal, but then again, that would make things even more complicated to add missing artist pictures.

[image: Example artist picture]

Answer (score 1):

I think the data comes from CDDB, or at least it used to, back in the day. You can edit (only add?) album art in iTunes by dragging image files onto the album art display. I don't know of any way to do it with only iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism in iOS for modifying album artwork associated with your music.

You'll need to use iTunes on Mac OS X or Windows. From there, you can manually choose your artwork, or ask iTunes to search for appropriate artwork.

Comment: Both answers are referring to album art. But I'm explicitly asking about artist pictures, which in the shown example, is Art Blakey hitting his drums. Sure, album art can be edited in iTunes, but that was not the question. I like the idea to add artist art at the top for the artist listing. But many artists do not yet have an image at that place.